# React-router: type.toUpperCase is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

when I first to use react-router, but page gives me this error below

**React-router: type.toUpperCase is not a function**

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');

var Route = Router.Route;

var App = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>App</div>
    );
  }
});

React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

it seems nothing wrong from the document, some one could help me?

where error comes here

```
function autoGenerateWrapperClass(type) {
    return ReactClass.createClass({
      tagName: type.toUpperCase(),
      render: function() {
        return new ReactElement(
          type,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          null,
          this.props
        );
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please add a stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 34):

The error you posted is cryptic but what it means is you are trying to render a component out of a variable that is not a real component. For example, you could do this and get the same kind of error:

```
render: function() {
  var Thing = {};  // not a component
  return <Thing />;  // same error
}
```

In the code you posted, `<Router>` maps to a variable that is a module, not a component. You can fix it with a new variable declaration:

```
var React = require('react');

var routerModule = require('react-router');
var Router = routerModule.Router;  // component

var Route = routerModule.Route;

var App = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>App</div>
    );
  }
});

React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: I saw this error because I hadn't exported the component and I was trying to use it. Easily found once I know what the error means, thanks.

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same error. Then I figure out that I did mistake while exporting my components. In one component I wrote module.export instead of module.exports. So, please check if you have done the same mistake.

Answer (score 3):

change the require statements:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
```

Comment: still error..and this way comes two warning like Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null or undefined. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
bundle.js:1730 Warning: Only functions or strings can be mounted as React components.

Comment: the `require` statements shouldn't cause the warnings. BTW: Your above code doesn't seem correct, so could you create a fiddle please?! or alternatively post your whole code?

Answer (score 0):

if you use react-router v0.13.3
replace Route**r** on Route,
like this:

```
var routes = (
  <Route>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Root) {
 React.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: no, i can't, because i don't speak english, just see [documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/doc/00%20Guides/Router%20Overview.md)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, it was circle dependency.

component1.jsx :

```
var Component1 = require('./component2.jsx');
```

component2.jsx :

```
var Component2 = require('./component1.jsx');
```

Seen like this, this is obvious, but the error message is very opaque.